# XMLHttpRequest in nodejs connection with javascript error

Tags: javascript, node.js, get, xmlhttprequest

I'm using node js to make a request,

```
var getdb = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "url";
getdb.open('GET', url, true);

getdb.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(getdb.readyState == 4 && getdb.status == 200)
       console.log("conn ok");
}
getdb.send();
```

If I open the url in browser it works, but if I call it with code, this is the response:

> This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in
> your browser or use a browser with Javascript support

The page is a simple php page with a db connection and some echo.

Comment: it seems you should active javascript support on your browser, please read this 
[link](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/12654?hl=en)

Comment: using `XMLHttpRequest` you will request the raw html without executing any scripts.

Comment: @masoud They're not trying to access the page in the browser, they're trying to make an HTTP request programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem, my free web hoster (profreehost.com) had disabled the programmatly requests, because they doesn't wont any abuse.